# Strange key bindings (Ubuntu 16.04 VM, xfce, Spice console)

Tags: keyboard, virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04, xfce

I have a Ubuntu 16.04.04 VM with xfce intalled. The VM is hosted by an academic HPC/cloud computing system ([Compute Canada](https://www.computecanada.ca/)), and I access it through their website which I believe has a Spice console. I'm new to a lot of this so I'm happy I made it this far.

[image]

My problem is some very strange key bindings. For example,

- when I try to type `p` in the Terminal it brings up the Display window and doesn't type `p`.
- `tab` switches between windows and doesn't autocomplete.
- I can't copy or paste. e.g. `ctrl-v` does nothing, and `cmd-v` acts as if I held the `v` key down ten seconds.
- Occasionally I can't type anything, but this is usually fixed by refreshing the browser window.

The `p`, `tab`, and lack of copy-paste are the big problems. For example, **in the picture above I can't complete the file name (`.zip`)**. This makes the VM practically unusable for what I'm doing. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer to my own question: I changed the Application Shortcuts in the Setting menu.

Specifically, I typed `xfce4-settings-manager` to open Settings. There was an entry in the Command column (`xfce-display-settings --minimal`) that was bound to `Super+P` and I removed it. Fixed that at least!